# Change name of variable displayed by validation in models for rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, variables

I am trying to make some validation for my tables but I am having trouble with the variable name that is displayed on my web page.

For example, in my users model I have the following code:
validates :regNumber, length: { is :9}

This returns the error message: "RegNumber is the wrong length (should be 9 characters)"

What I would like for it to return is "Registration number is..." or even "Reg number...".
After some research I found that I can do this using the /config/locales/en.yml file but I am not sure how it works.

Is anyone able to help me? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to do it without using locales

In your model, add the following code

```
def self.human_attribute_name(attr)
  return "Registration Number" if attr.to_sym == :regNumber
  super
end
```

Comment: This way produces an error, but the locales way worked fine. I wrote almost the same thing before but I wrote "users" instead of "user" which made it not work.
I also thought of another question with a similar problem (sorry if it is obvious, only recently started using rails).

I have(in another table, called students) on the index page a search form using ransack. The way I have it coded, I can add any search query I want, but I have the same problem as here since every field name is displayed the same way as it is declared (firstName, regNumber etc etc). Can I fix that using the same way?

Comment: Yes you can use the same solution for your student model too